# How do I handle two dropdown post values?

Tags: php, mysql

I have three dropdown by default. The first dropdown value will affect the visibility of the 2nd and 3rd dropdown. For example, choose option one, hide 3rd dropdown, show 2nd dropdown. 2nd and 3rd dropdown will hold the value of the same column in database.

```
<select class="ui fluid selection dropdown dd" name="category1" id="category1">
    <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
    <option value="">Which category does this fall into?</option>
    <option value="1">Gestures</option>
    <option value="2">Etiquette</option>
</select>
<?php if(isset($_POST['category1'])) { $category1 = $_POST['category1']; }?>

<div class="category2" >
   <select class="ui fluid selection dropdown dd" name="category2" id="category2" >
        <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
        <option value="">Be specific...</option>
        <option value="1">Friendly gestures</option>
        <option value="2">Gestures of respect</option>
        <option value="3">Salutes</option>
        <option value="4">Celebratory gestures</option>
        <option value="5">Finger-counting</option>
        <option value="6">Obscene gestures</option>
        <option value="7">Taunts</option>
        <option value="8">Head motions</option>
        <option value="9">Other gestures</option>
    </select>
</div>
<?php if(isset($_POST['category2'])) { $category2 = $_POST['category2']; }?>

<div class="category3" style="display:none!important;">
    <select class="ui fluid selection dropdown dd" name="category3" id="category3">
        <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
        <option value="">Be specific...</option>
        <option value="10">Greetings</option>
        <option value="11">Making payment</option>
        <option value="12">Visiting someone's house</option>
        <option value="13">Gifts and gift-giving</option>
        <option value="14">Table manners</option>
        <option value="15">Eating and drinking</option>
        <option value="16">Funerals</option>
        <option value="17">Bars and restaurants</option>
        <option value="18">Driving</option>
        <option value="19">Business etiquette</option>
        <option value="20">Hierarchy and honoring the elder</option>
    </select>
</div>
<?php if(isset($_POST['category3'])) { $category3 = $_POST['category3']; }?>
```

Now, $category2 and $category3 represent the same column in database. If I were to make an insert query, how do I make sure either dropdown value is posted and will be stored?

```
mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO practices(category1,category2) VALUES('$category1','$category2 or $category3')")
```

I tried this, and

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['category2'])) { $category2 = $_POST['category2']; }?>
<?php if(isset($_POST['category3'])) { $category2 = $_POST['category3']; }?>
```

This one worked for one of the dropdown only, and error inserting for another. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Save previously posted value in a hidden field and then post again with the second dropdown list.

```
    <div class="category3" style="display:none!important;">


<?php if(isset($_POST['category2'])) 
{ 
    echo'<select name="pre_category" >
    <option selected="selected" value="'.$_POST['category2'].'">'.$_POST['category2'].' </option> 
    </select>';
 } ?>
    <select class="ui fluid selection dropdown dd" name="category3" id="category3">
        <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
        <option value="">Be specific...</option>
        <option value="10">Greetings</option>
        <option value="11">Making payment</option>
        <option value="12">Visiting someone's house</option>
        <option value="13">Gifts and gift-giving</option>
        <option value="14">Table manners</option>
        <option value="15">Eating and drinking</option>
        <option value="16">Funerals</option>
        <option value="17">Bars and restaurants</option>
        <option value="18">Driving</option>
        <option value="19">Business etiquette</option>
        <option value="20">Hierarchy and honoring the elder</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Now you can find the value from *pre_category*